# Take last section of URL and return it in Excel

Tags: excel, formula

My problem I need to solve is to rip apart the last section of a URL.

I have the URL

```
.../one/two/three/four
```

and need to have

```
four
```

OR

```
/four
```

I used Excel function

```
=RIGHT(F2;SEARCH("/";F2))
```

But it returns

```
r
```

Anyone have a solution for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you `four`

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))),1))
```

this get you `/four`

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))),1)+1)
```

Source: [Find Position of the Last Occurrence of a Character in a String in Excel](https://trumpexcel.com/find-characters-last-position/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using `FILTERXML` (available from Excel 2013 and later):

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1;"/";"</s><s>")&"</s></t>";"//s[last()]")
```

This formula will first build an XML string like this

```
<t><s>...</s><s>one</s><s>two</s><s>three</s><s>four</s></t>
```

and then extract the last node.

There has recently been a nice question here on Stackoverflow that I highly recommend to read:

[Excel - Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/12418842)

Comment: You should add that this solution is only available in Excel 2013 or higher

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Thank you, I have edited my post. Even though I assume most people use Office 2013 or newer.

Comment: Note that FILTERXML is not available on a Mac. Sigh. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7